# Convert String into String array

Tags: java

I have this String from a JSON value:

```
["1","5","10","15","20"]
```

I need to get a string array from this string. How do I do that?

Comment: try do `yourstring.split(",")` which gives u string array?

Comment: I would imagine that removing the first and last characters and then using `split()` would do it if you're looking for an array consisting of "1", "5", "10", "15", and "20".

Comment: Remove the first two characters, the last two characters and `split()` on `"\",\""`

Comment: Why is your JavaScript sending a string instead of an array? Can't JSON handle arrays?

Comment: It's Java, not JavaScript

Comment: this is not java script,its java and json part is don by someone else. i can't modify it.otherwise Json can handle arrays

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [gson library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); // create gson instance

String[] strArr = gson.fromJson(jsonString, String[].class);
```

Comment: If you're reading JSON values, you should use a JSON-parsing library.  Don't try to parse them yourself because you won't be able to handle every possible invalid input (with the proper exception) unless you put a lot of extra (and unnecessary) effort into it.